# Rendering a graph as a tree

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, voila, ipycytoscape

I am using ipyvuetify and Ipycytoscape to create a dashboard rendered with voila.

I need to create graph data structures as this one:
[image]

This structure IS NOT rendered with ipycytoscape.

Does anyone knows which layout should I use to avoid that ipycytoscape just random places the nodes and ensure that the parents are always on top of the children.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the `dagre` layout?
It was supposed to achive this kind of result out of the box :)